# Model Include option to return attributes as single value with defined alias instead of an object with properties

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, sequelize.js

I have 2 models:

- `Property`
- `Account`

A `Property` `hasOne` `Account`

#### Property

```
Property.belongsTo(models.Account, {
  as: 'account',
  foreignKey: 'accountNumber'
});
```

#### Account

```
Account.hasOne(models.Property, {
  as: 'property',
  foreignKey: 'accountNumber'
});
```

On a `findAll` query I have

```
const properties = await Property.findAll({
 attributes: ['accountNumber'],
 include: [
      {
        model: Models.Account,
        as: 'account',
        attributes: ['organisation', 'email'],  
      },
 ]
});
```

This returns an object for each item like;

```
{ 
  "accountNumber":"AC0012",
  "account":{ 
    "organisation":"Example Org",
    "email":"email@email.com"
  }
}
```

However, what I aim to achieve is something like,

```
{ 
  "accountNumber":"AC0012",
  "accountOrganisation":"Example Org",
  "accountEmail":"email@email.com"
}
```

The current MySQL query is as follows;

```
SELECT `Property`.`id`, 
`Property`.`account_number` AS `accountNumber`, 
`account`.`account_number` AS `account.accountNumber`, 
`account`.`organisation` AS `account`.`organisation`, 
`account`.`email` AS `account.email` 
FROM `property_dev`.`property` 
AS `Property` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `property_dev`.`account` AS `account` 
ON `Property`.`account_number` = `account`.`account_number`
```

I need to update the aliases used from;

```
`account`.`organisation` AS `account`.`organisation`, 
`account`.`email` AS `account.email`
```

to

```
`account`.`organisation` AS `accountOrganisation`, 
`account`.`email` AS `accountEmail`
```

How can I achieve this? It seems like something that's quite simple but I can't seem to query the correct solution. I may be using the incorrect terms in my searches, going through the official docs haven't lead me to the solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alias the joined columns using an array with `[value, key]`, where value is the `sequelize.col()` value of the included model. Since you want just the raw JSON results you can also pass in `raw: true` to not parse the results to Model Instances for better performance.

```js
const properties = await Property.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'accountNumber',
    [sequelize.col('account.organisation'), 'accountOrganisation'],
    [sequelize.col('account.email'), 'accountEmail'],
  ],
  include: {
    model: Models.Account,
    as: 'account',
    attributes: [],
  },
  raw: true,
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, very helpful. I have 2 different databases defined in the `\models/index.js` so I didn't have the conventional `sequelize` I had to do `Models.Database1.col` instead, where `Models` is the default import from the `\models/index.js` file. Just in case someone else has any similar setup.

Comment: Also, if you happen to know where `cols` is referenced in the docs, could you send me a link, just to see if I was looking in the wrong place all along?

Comment: @mcclosa the documentation is here: https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-col

Comment: In this case `sequelize` is the object returned by `new Sequelize()`

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated